# React-Native: app is crash on Launch

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

My application is working fine with local server without any issue. But when I try to generate Release build, its not working properly. Application is crashed as soon as we click on icon. I tried to check ViewPropTypes and update in necessary places. But still having same issue.

Here is log:

```
07-12 15:02:49.003 2675-2675/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:50777871 intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=IDENTIFERNAME/.MainActivity bnds=[53,264][175,386] (has extras) }
07-12 15:02:49.010 1399-2562/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=IDENTIFERNAME/.MainActivity bnds=[53,264][175,386] (has extras)} from uid 10027 on display 0
07-12 15:02:49.048 1399-2562/? D/Boost: hostingType=activity, hostingName=IDENTIFERNAME/.MainActivity, callerPackage=com.miui.home, isSystem=true, isBoostNeeded=false.
07-12 15:02:49.048 1399-2562/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 30529:IDENTIFERNAME/u0a471 for activity IDENTIFERNAME/.MainActivity caller=com.miui.home
07-12 15:02:49.100 2614-2784/? I/WtProcessController: MOVE TO FOREGROUND: IDENTIFERNAME 10471
07-12 15:02:49.100 2614-2784/? I/StatusController: Last foreground:com.miui.home uid:10027 Current foreground:IDENTIFERNAME uid:10471
07-12 15:02:49.100 2614-2784/? I/WtProcessController: FOREGROUND INFO: name=IDENTIFERNAME uid=10471 pid=30529 TaskId:140
07-12 15:02:49.287 30529-30553/? V/FA: App package, google app id: IDENTIFERNAME, 1:110722844580:android:2c647de8d50b0447
07-12 15:02:49.293 30529-30553/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                         adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app IDENTIFERNAME
07-12 15:02:49.302 30529-30529/? V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/IDENTIFERNAME/lib-main
07-12 15:02:49.304 30529-30529/? I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/IDENTIFERNAME/lib-main
07-12 15:02:49.304 30529-30529/? V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/IDENTIFERNAME/lib-main
07-12 15:02:49.409 30529-30529/? D/AccessibilityManager: current package=IDENTIFERNAME, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=true, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
07-12 15:02:49.483 30529-30566/? I/art: Thread[22,tid=30566,Native,Thread*=0xe48a4d00,peer=0x12c7d670,"Thread-4"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/IDENTIFERNAME-1/lib/arm/libfb.so"
07-12 15:02:49.807 1399-1472/? I/ActivityManager: Displayed IDENTIFERNAME/.MainActivity: +773ms
07-12 15:02:49.807 1399-1472/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{9279ddf u0 IDENTIFERNAME/.MainActivity t140} time:50778675
07-12 15:02:49.867 2939-29226/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='IDENTIFERNAME', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=2636, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=4013702848528184958}]}
07-12 15:02:49.911 2939-29226/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='IDENTIFERNAME', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4603722032159587411}]}
07-12 15:02:51.431 30529-30581/? I/ReactNativeJS: Running application "StreetTune" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON
07-12 15:02:51.532 1399-5932/? D/LocationManagerService: request 5c27842 gps Request[ACCURACY_FINE gps requested=+100ms fastest=+100ms] from IDENTIFERNAME(10471)
07-12 15:02:51.537 1399-5932/? D/LocationManagerService: request 20da689 network Request[POWER_LOW network requested=+1s0ms fastest=+1s0ms] from IDENTIFERNAME(10471)
07-12 15:02:51.580 30529-30583/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
                                                   Process: IDENTIFERNAME, PID: 30529
                                                   com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Module JSTimers is not a registered callable module (calling callTimers), stack:
                                                   value@30:2875
                                                   <unknown>@30:955
                                                   value@30:2417
                                                   value@30:927

                                                       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:56)
                                                       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:40)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:374)
                                                       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:162)
                                                       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                                                       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:194)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:760)
07-12 15:02:51.636 2614-21189/? I/ActiveController: loadActiveApp type: 4, name: IDENTIFERNAME, uid: 10471, pid: 0, status: 10
07-12 15:02:51.671 1649-1649/? V/ExpandedNotification: push score:0.0, local score:0.0, pkg:IDENTIFERNAME
07-12 15:02:51.673 1649-1649/? D/PhoneStatusBar: addNotification pkg=IDENTIFERNAME;basepkg=com.android.systemui;id=252119
07-12 15:02:51.795 2939-29226/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='IDENTIFERNAME', name='app_exception(_ae)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4603722032159587411, timestamp=1531387971585, fatal=1}]}
07-12 15:02:51.889 2939-29226/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='IDENTIFERNAME', name='user_engagement(_e)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=2279, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-4603722032159587411}]}
07-12 15:02:51.894 2614-2784/? I/WtProcessController: Receive am_crash event for pid: 30529 pkg = IDENTIFERNAME
07-12 15:02:51.894 2614-2784/? W/KloServer: Aborted broadcast does not supprt for: IDENTIFERNAME
07-12 15:02:51.898 1399-2562/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity IDENTIFERNAME/.MainActivity
07-12 15:02:51.989 2614-2784/? I/StatusController: Last foreground:IDENTIFERNAME uid:10471 Current foreground:com.miui.home uid:10027
07-12 15:02:52.075 1399-5932/? I/WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{91f64f4 u0 IDENTIFERNAME/IDENTIFERNAME.MainActivity}
07-12 15:02:52.076 1399-1562/? I/ActivityManager: Process IDENTIFERNAME (pid 30529) has died: vis  +99T 
07-12 15:02:52.164 2675-2675/? I/Launcher.ApplicationsMessage: update IDENTIFERNAME/ to null
```

Can anyone help me out this issue?

[image]

Comment: are you using firebase ?

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/653

Comment: Yeah, we are using it for push. But this issue is not occur before.

Comment: Can you check if index.android.bundle is updated, when you generate release build? Maybe it is using the stale one.

Comment: @AlokJha this issue is happen for both iphone and Android. And both are update.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got an answer after spending 4 days behind it. The issue is that Android will contain the older version file in `index.android.js`. The code in it is previous build and its create an issue. In iOS, as we delete the **build** folder its solve.

Try to create a fresh file which require for react-native. Below are the command which help to solve the issue.

Android:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

iOS:

```
react-native bundle --platform ios  --dev false --assets-dest ./ios --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle
```

Answer (score 0):

Some tips to debug:

1. If you are in Android you can run debug version of Android app with
   Production bundle disabling dev bundle from Dev Settings.
2. If you want you can also enable minify to find whether this is a
       minify issue.
3. One more bad idea is generate a production build and open
       the bundle file and navigate to 837:1752 so you will come to know
       where does this occurs.

And I don't see any error in the Log if possible can you post the
    complete log?

Comment: I have put whole log which I get from Android Studios.

Comment: As you see, it's a JavascriptException so the above debug tips will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of things you can check:

1. Is build proguard enabled? If yes then disable and try to run and check. You will get to know exact error and obj detail.
2. Is the env for debug and release same? - you are trying to call login_type on null object.
3. You can add null check where you are calling login_type and test release build.
4. If nothing works, Last option - Integrate bug snag crash reporting. This is really cool javascript lib and will provide more detail on crash.

Thanks.